# How to resolve warning for `unstableOnSplit` prop on a DOM element in block editor

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor

**Here is my code -**

```
return (
                <RichText
                    tagName="div"
                    value={ author_name }
                    placeholder={ __( "Author Name" ) }
                    className='uagb-tm__author-name'
                    onChange={ ( value ) => { 
                        var new_content = { "description" : data_copy[index_value]["description"], "name":value, "company" : data_copy[index_value]["company"], "image" : data_copy[index_value]["image"]  }
                        data_copy[index_value] = new_content
                        setAttributes( { "test_block": data_copy } )                        
                    } }     
                    onMerge = { props.mergeBlocks }
                    unstableOnSplit = {
                        props.insertBlocksAfter ?
                            ( before, after, ...blocks ) => {
                                setAttributes( { content: before } )
                                props.insertBlocksAfter( [
                                    ...blocks,
                                    createBlock( "core/paragraph", { content: after } ),
                                ] )
                            } :
                            undefined
                    }
                    onRemove={ () => props.onReplace( [] ) }
                />
            )
```

Comment: And what is the warning you get?

Comment: In [the current gutenberg master](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/heading/edit.js#L59) there's an 'onSplit' not 'unstableOnSplit'. Or `__unstableOnSplitAtEnd` or `__unstableOnSplitMiddle`.

Comment: Thanks, @Rup using `onSplit` instead of `unstableOnSplit` resolve the issue.